# No Thumbnail visible when YouTube video is embedded with iframe using Internet Explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, youtube

I've recently noticed Internet Explorer (10) does not show video thumbnails when embedded in a webpage with iframe.  The video title over a black screen is the only thing visible.
Thumbnails are visible in Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Android browsers.

Interestingly, videos embedded with the old style object do show the thumbnails in Internet Explorer.

Just wondering if anybody else can confirm this observation or would have a solution. I kind of feel this is another reason to hate Microsoft.

Comment: I am having the same issue, looking for information about this.

Comment: For infos, i use that type of linking and now it works ( www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9eXzmVzDR8 ) instead of ( www.youtube.com/embed/Y9eXzmVzDR8 )

Comment: Not working, OK, can you provide html ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `/watch?v=`   parameter

like `www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9eXzmVzDR8`

instead of `www.youtube.com/embed/Y9eXzmVzDR8`

Comment: the /watch?v= doesn't work for me. The video will not show at all with this parameter.

Comment: Good, interraction .. Can you provide the html.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<iframe width="100%" height="620" src="&gt?php echo str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/",$video1); ?>?autoplay=1&controls=0&mute=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" style="pointer-events: none"></iframe>"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).